# Trying to work with the github js api but it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, github, coffeescript

I run these lines using https://github.com/michael/github

```
issues = github.getIssues "twbs", "bootstrap"

console.log issues

issues.list (err, issues) ->
  console.log issues
```

And the first part works `Github.Issue {list: function}`, but then it says

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
    (anonymous function) github.js:585
    _request.xhr.onreadystatechange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issues.list() accepts two arguments:

```
issues.list(options, function(err, issues) {});
```

You're trying to call it with one argument. It complains that the second argument is `undefined` instead of a callback.